# How to access Git source of a build artifact from an Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to make a release pipeline that works (makes a release package) on the codebase that has been tested by a build pipeline.

How can I make a release that accesses the Git code-base that a specific build pipeline has been successfully completed from?

Notes:

- Making the release package is time consuming, so I don't want to include that into the build if possible. Making the release package in my case requires the source files (nearly all).
- I could solve this by copying the entire Git repository to the build artifacts of the build and then use a build artifact, but I don't like this as it requires putting the entire codebase to the artifacts.
- I was also trying to specify two artifacts for the release: a build and a git one, but I could not figure out how to synchronize the two (the git should use the commit used by the build). For the Git one I can select "a specific commit", but I could not figure out how to specify the commit of the build artifact there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify two artifacts for the release: a build and a git one. You can use the [predefined release variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---general-artifact) `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion` to synchronize the commit used by the build and the commit of the git artifacts.

This variable `Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceVersion` returns the commit hash from which the build artifact is built. So you can add a script task in your release pipeline to checkout the specific commit. See below example scripts in the powershell task:

```
cd  _theGitArtifactsAliasName
git checkout $(Release.Artifacts._TheBuildArtifactsAliasName.SourceVersion)
```

Then the artifacts of the git will be on the commit of the build artifacts.

[image]

Comment: Works nicely for normal commits! For PR builds it does not work (not needed anyway), but since it would silently keep the head this way, I have added a `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b 1` line after the git checkout, so that it fails at least for PR builds.